# Converter número em data

Tags: php, data, conversão-de-tipo

Boa tarde,

Gostaria de saber, se há como converter número em data no PHP.

> Exemplo, no Excel o número 42873 é equivalente a data 18-05-2017. E tenho como fazer o contrário também.

Existe alguma função no PHP, ao qual eu consiga fazer essa conversão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datas no Excel são armazenadas em números de dias a partir de 1 de Janeiro de 1900, portanto para datas após esse período você pode criar um objeto `DateTime` e formatar a data para exibição, exemplo:

```
$n = 42873;
$dateTime = new DateTime("1899-12-30 + $n days");
echo $dateTime->format("d/m/Y");
```

[Exemplo Ideone](https://ideone.com/qntb6B)

[Confira esta resposta no SOE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963096/convert-excel-dateserial-back-to-a-readable-date-format)

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo sua ajuda @abfulan, usei seu exemplo no meu código e o mesmo funcionou perfeitamente.

Mais uma vez, muito obrigado!

Comment: @TonyAnderson Legal!

Answer (score 0):

```
string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp ] )
```

> O parâmetro opcional timestamp é um integer Unix timestamp cujo padrão
>   é a hora local se timestamp não for informado. Em outras palavras, o
>   padrão é o valor da função time().

Veja mais sobre o [date.](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php) 
Mais informações [nesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617100/php-converting-integer-to-date-reverse-of-strtotime) resposta.

Answer (score -2):

Alguns sistemas exportam as datas para excel já no formato de data em excel.
Visto que as Datas no Excel são armazenadas em números de dias a partir de 1 de Janeiro de 1900, com base em uma das respostas desse tópico.

Sugiro utilizar a biblioteca CARBON:

```
$dt_number = intVal($dado['data']);
if (is_numeric($dt_number)) {
    $dt = new Carbon('1899-12-30');
    $dt = $dt->addDays($dt_number);
}
```